# Running query from scratch with something like exec function?

Tags: postgresql

is it possible to make something similar to the following with Postgresql without using a function?

pseudo sql code:

select * from sometable where somecol = somevalue AND someothercol IN **exec( 'select something from exclusionlist' )**

My primary intention is to build up a table with predefined queries to call inside a where clause

pseudo sql code:
select * from sometable where somecol = somevalue AND someothercol IN **exec( select query from predefinedqueries where id=someid )**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the only option is:

```
prepare my_usr_id as select usr_id from usr where usr_id < $1;
create temp table my_temp on commit drop as execute my_usr_id(10);
select * from usr join my_temp using (usr_id);
```

Comment: Thank You, really a good suggestion, even more than what I figured out in my question